# Staggered Top Alignment JPanels

Tags: java, jpanel, vertical-alignment

I am attempting to use a FlowLayout to get my panels to align vertically.  I want the bottom right to align toward the bottom of the top right panel, not the bottom of that row.

Here is what I have done:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;



    public class BigPanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public Component.BaselineResizeBehavior getBaselineResizeBehavior() {
        return Component.BaselineResizeBehavior.CONSTANT_ASCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getBaseline(int width, int height) {
       return 0;
    }

public BigPanel() {
    FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
    layout.setAlignOnBaseline(true);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    this.add(new Panel1()); // size: 340x, 160y
    this.add(new Panel2()); // size: 340x, 120y
    this.add(new Panel3()); // size: 340x, 160y
    this.add(new Panel4()); // size: 340x, 300y
}
```

}

How can I simply anchor panels and components to a set of coordinates? I have run into this problem many times this last week and use ridiculous workarounds for my jlabels, etc.

How it looks now:

[image]

Comment: This is the nature of `FlowLayout`.  The only layout I can think of that might be able to achieve this out of the box is `GridBagLayout`, but that seems like a lot work for little gain.  The other choice would be to use something like a `GridLayout` and create two panels, one for each column, and layout the sub components separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably a few ways you can achieve this, but the simplest would be to use compound layouts.

Use two panels to act as the columns and then place these onto the main container.  Into these you would then place you other components.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class CompundLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CompundLayout();
    }

    public CompundLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {

            JPanel left = new JPanel();
            JPanel right = new JPanel();

            setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 2, 2));

            left.add(createPane(Color.RED));
            left.add(createPane(Color.GREEN));
            right.add(createPane(Color.BLUE));
            right.add(createPane(Color.MAGENTA));

            add(left);
            add(right);

        }

        protected JPanel createPane(Color color) {

            SimplePane pane = new SimplePane();
            pane.setBorder(new LineBorder(color));

            return pane;

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public class SimplePane extends JPanel {

        private int width;
        private int height;

        public SimplePane() {

            width = 100;
            height = 50 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

            return new Dimension(width, height);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the method. That's what I ended up doing. However, I have encountered a lot of issues with more complex panels with boxes needing multiple labels, etc., so I was wondering if it's possible to anchor things by their top left corner (or center - it's just a quick adjustment) to a set of pixel coordinates.

Comment: Pixel positing is ill advised, as the font properties you are develops with most likely won't be the font properties of the client machine. The only layout you'll find tht provides anchoring capabilities in the Sstandard JDK is GridBagLayout, but I think you'll end up in night mare trying to get it to work the way you want

Comment: Why do font properties matter if they're all in fixed-size components like a JLabel?

Comment: Label isn't fixed size, it is dependent on the now big the font will render under the current settings of the OS, things like the font point, DPI and screen size will change there how much room they will require to render. Even across the OS on different PCs, the font metrics can be different. This is the point of layout managers, to take the guess work out of it